# dynamicaly set nginx location in configuration file

Tags: nginx

I want my nginx location dynamically 
For example

```
 ~* /profile/{{anything}}  {
     alias C:/bitbucket/profiles/app/modules/profile;
index profile.html;
    }
```

How can i achieve that?

Comment: You just want to ignore `anything`?

Comment: no anything can be like /profile/1234 or /profile/profileid

Comment: Still not clear. Show some sample URLs and what files should be served for them

Comment: Ok let me explain you.
Suppose there are two profile id 915 and 698
and my link will be www.exmaple.com/profile/915 or www.exmaple.com/profile/698 or www.exmaple.com/profile/{{anyprofileid}}

Comment: Don't write it in comments. Put it into post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me explain you. Suppose there are two profile id 915 and 698 and my link will be www.exmaple.com/profile/915 or www.exmaple.com/profile/698 or www.exmaple.com/profile/{{anyprofileid}} –